# Convert numbers to words, e.g., 111 = one hundred eleven, using the "Indian numbering system"

Tags: numbering, strings

May I know if there is method for typesetting numbers to words using LaTeX. I have created an invoice in which I would like to convert the invoice amount to words. E.g., "1,23,456.00" should be typeset as "One Lakh Twenty Three Thousand Four Hundred Fifty Six Only".

Thanks a lot in advance ~

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For me, your number sounds strange (I would think of it as `123,456.00` and "one hundred twenty-three thousand four hundred fifty-six [unit] zero [smaller unit]" to remove some edge cases). Could you please make a small example of what you have tried (MWE)?

Answer (score 11):

Here's an easy version spelling out currencies (as an example with Euros). Please note that you have to input the number and its decimal places separately.

[image: spell out]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numname}

\newcommand\majorUnit{Euros}
\newcommand\minorUnit{Cents}
\newcommand\spellOutCurrency[2]{%
    \NumToName{#1}\,\majorUnit\ and \NumToName{#2}\,\minorUnit%
}

\begin{document}
\spellOutCurrency{123456}{00}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Careful about the "ands". I think 456 is just  "four hundred fifty six".

Comment: @EthanBolker That might be, but I have not written this (that "and" is fixed in `numname`). As the OP did not specify his exact needs I will leave the answer as simple as possible.

Comment: @EthanBolker The UK and the US have different conventions regarding the use of "and" when spelling out numbers.

Comment: Can the `numname` package handle Indian-number-system conventions, which uses multiples of **lakh** (10^5), **crore** (10^7), and **lakh crore** (10^12)?

Comment: @Mico No, it does not handle anything but English number to word conversion in the decimal numbering system.

Comment: How do you convert 150000 to one lakh fifty thousand rather than one hundred fifty thousand?

Answer (score 10):

(updated the answer to allow for fractional parts in the numbers as well as for very large numbers (>10^12))

(Sept. 2019: Updated 1 line in the Lua code, to make it work correctly under versions of LuaTeX which are based on Lua 5.3 -- which has a separate numeric entry type called `integer`.)

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution that expresses numbers in words while using the so-called [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). This system uses multiples of **lakh** (`10^5`), **crore** (`10^7`), and **lakh crore** (`10^12`) instead of **million**, **billion**, and **trillion** to denote large numbers.

The code consists of 2 Lua utility functions, a Lua function called `num2word`, and a LaTeX macro called `\numtoword`, which is just a front-end or "wrapper" for the `num2word` function. The argument of `\numtoword` must be either a positive number or an expression that evaluates to a positive number under the usual rules of Lua syntax, e.g., `1+1+1`, `2e7`, and `3*10^5`.

Commas are *not* allowed in the input of `\numtoword`. I.e., don't write `\num2word{1,000,000}` ("Western" system) or `\numtoword{10,00,000}` ("Indian" system), Instead, write `\num2word{1000000}` or `\num2word{1e6}`.

If the number contains a fractional part, the fractional part is rounded automatically to 2 digits. Most modern currencies I'm familiar contain a "cent" component, i.e., a fractional part that is a multiple of `0.01`.

If the number is smaller than 1 lakh (10^5) and if the number's fractional part equals 0, the suffix "Only" is appended to the word string; if the number's fractional part is nonzero, its word-equivalent (using "Hundredths") is appended. Finally, if the number is either exactly equal to 0 or is a large integer (>=1e5) which consists only of lakh, crore, and/or lakh crore (but no ten-thousands component), the "Only" suffix is not appended.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % optional
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % for "\Verb" macro
\usepackage{numname}  % for "\NumToName" macro 
  % Modify some of the macros of the 'numname' package
  \renewcommand*{\namenumbercomma}{ } % default: "{, }"
  \renewcommand*\tensunitsep{ }       % default: "{-}"
  \renewcommand*{\namenumberand}{ }   % default: "{ and }"

\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- Utility function: Round number to nearest integer
function math.round ( x )
   return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
end

-- Typeset non-integer part of the number
function displaycents ( c , flag )
  -- value of 'flag' can be either '1' or '0'
  if flag==1 then
    if c==0 then
      tex.sprint ( " Only" )
    elseif c==1 then
      tex.sprint ( " and One Hundreth" )
    else
      tex.sprint ( " and \\NumToName{" .. c .. "} Hundreths" )
    end
  elseif flag==0 then
    if c==0 then
      tex.sprint ( "Zero" )
    elseif c==1 then
      tex.sprint ( "One Hundreth" )
    else
      tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. c .. "} Hundreths" )
    end
  end
end

-- 'num2name' is the main lua function
function num2name ( n )
  local cents, lakhcrore, crore, lakh, rem
  -- Retrieve decimal and integer parts of 'n'
  cents = math.round ( 100 * ( n-math.floor(n) ) ) 
  n     = math.floor ( n ) -- integer part

  -- calculate number of lakh crore, crore, lakh, and rem
  lakhcrore = math.floor ( n / 1e12 )    -- lakh crore
  crore = math.floor ( (n % 1e12) / 1e7 )-- crore
  lakh  = math.floor ( (n % 1e7) / 1e5 ) -- lakh
  rem   = math.floor ( n % 1e5 )         -- remainder % modified 2019-09-23

  if n>0 then    -- number >= 1.00
    if lakhcrore>0 then
      if crore==0 then
        tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. lakhcrore .. "} Lakh Crore" )
      else 
        tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. lakhcrore .. "} Lakh" )
      end
      if crore>0 or lakh>0 or rem>0 then tex.sprint (" ") end
    end
    if crore>0 then
      tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. crore .. "} Crore" )
      if lakh>0 or rem>0 then tex.sprint (" ") end
    end
    if lakh>0 then
      tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. lakh .. "} Lakh" )
      if rem>0 then tex.sprint (" ") end
    end
    if rem>0 then
      tex.sprint ( "\\NumToName{" .. rem .. "}" ) 
      -- display fractional part ("cents")
      displaycents ( cents , 1 )  
    end
  else --    0 <= number <= 0.99
    displaycents ( cents , 0 )
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX wrapper macro:
\newcommand\numtoword[1]{\directlua{num2name(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\Verb:10^5:  & \numtoword{10^5}   \\
\Verb:2e7:   & \numtoword{2e7}    \\
\Verb:3e12:  & \numtoword{3e12}   \\
\Verb:6789e8: & \numtoword{6789e10} \\
\Verb:456e5: & \numtoword{456e5}  \\
\Verb:123456:& \numtoword{123456} \\
\Verb:123456.78: & \numtoword{123450+6.78} \\
\Verb:1:     & \numtoword{1}    \\
\Verb:0:     & \numtoword{0}    \\
\Verb:0.01:  & \numtoword{0.01} \\ 
\Verb:0.51:  & \numtoword{0.51} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```