# typing a number formatted as currency

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, currency

while typesetting indian currency such as 100000 the comma , is placed after three digits first and then after every two digits--1,00,000--how do we do it in latex?? i need to have the profit in rupees formatted as xx,xx,xx,xxx/--

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{ Profit}
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
       \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{profit earned}}\\

\hline

Apr 2018    &   70263.78\\
May 2018    &   33759.19\\
Jun 2018    &   39554.66\\
Jul 2018    &   51529.42\\
Aug 2018    &   46292.94\\
Sep 2018    &   32186.44\\
Oct 2018    &   42185.60\\
Nov 2018    &   31372.17\\
Dec 2018    &   12853.60\\
Jan 2019    &   2602.42\\
Feb 2019    &   33776.46\\
Mar 2019    &   318773.33\\
Apr 2019    &   0.00\\
May 2019    &   0.00\\
Jun 2019    &   0.00\\
Jul 2019    &   17455.88\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
       \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{profit distributed}}\\

\hline

diqa    &   20150\\
dqacv   &   47164\\
cqahv   &   188582\\
cqava   &   75433\\
cqavl   &   66004\\
Reserve &   48346\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: Inside a table the digits are misaligned--however in normal paragraph use the macro is perfect--why so??

[image]

```
\subsection*{Fixed Deposit} 
\begin{tabular}{lS}
\hline


Fixed Deposit                           &   \indiancurrency{2264812}\\
\hline
\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{{Dt of deposit}}\\ 
\hline\\
06 Mar 2018 &   \indiancurrency{1500000}\\
%\multicolumn{2}{l}{{Dt of deposit  }}\\
01 Nov 2016 &   \indiancurrency{764812}\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please use the code field to enter the mwe. And linebreaks would be helpful to understand your code...

Comment: Also, this is not a minimal WORKING example... Please make it working...

Comment: Did you manage to run it like this? There is still am % too much and the lines of the table are not well ended...

Comment: Can you explain further, how you want the number to be formatted? Should 318773.33 become 3,18,773.33 ?

Comment: Should 318773.33 become 3,18,773.33--------yes pls

Comment: Potentially of relevance: [Convert numbers to words, e.g., 111 = one hundred eleven, using the “Indian numbering system”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448845/5001).

Comment: Also for the edit: The example is not working. We can only guess, how you implemented the code, suggested below. Please make it as easy as possible, to help you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fully expandable implementation in `expl3`. The amount can be given with a decimal part or none; in either case `/` is appended and the decimal part shown, with at least two decimal digits (but an em-dash in case the decimal part is zero).

The idea is first to split at the possible decimal point, then process the integral part. This is done by producing the number if less than 1000; otherwise the last three digits are detached and the remaining digits are processed by pairs (prepending `{}` in case the number of digits is odd). Then a comma is added and the last three digit delivered.

For the decimal part `/` is appended, then it is checked whether the part is missing or zero, when an en-dash is delivered; otherwise the decimal part is delivered, with a trailing 0 if it is a single digit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\indiancurrency}{m}
 {
  \bibra_format_number:w #1 .. \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bibra_format_number:w #1 . #2 . #3 \q_stop
 {
  \bibra_format_number:n { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
   { / --- }
   { / \__bibra_format_decimal:n { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__bibra_format_decimal:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 0 }
   { --- }
   { #1 \int_compare:nT { \tl_count:n { #1 } = 1 } { 0 } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bibra_format_number:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
   { 0 }
   { \__bibra_format_integral:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__bibra_format_integral:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 < 1000 }
   { #1 }
   {
    \__bibra_format_thousands:e { \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -4 } }
    ,
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -3 } { -1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__bibra_format_thousands:n #1
 {
  \int_if_odd:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    \__bibra_format_comma:nn {}#1 \q_nil \q_stop
   }
   {
    \__bibra_format_comma:nn  #1 \q_nil \q_stop
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__bibra_format_thousands:n { e }

\cs_new:Npn \__bibra_format_comma:nn #1 #2
 {
  #1 #2 \__bibra_format_comma_again:nn
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__bibra_format_comma_again:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_if_eq:NNF  #1 \q_nil
   {
    , #1 #2 \__bibra_format_comma_again:nn
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\indiancurrency{.34}

\indiancurrency{.3}

\indiancurrency{12}

\indiancurrency{12.3}

\indiancurrency{12.0}

\indiancurrency{12.34}

\indiancurrency{1234.56}

\indiancurrency{12345.67}

\indiancurrency{123456.78}

\indiancurrency{1234567.89}

\indiancurrency{12345678.90}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does the work!!! beautiful